# Find the cause why page refreshes when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking in one of 3 different buttons (different onclicks, different ids) the page refreshes itself, it started today, but all day i added a lot of new functions so its becoming very difficult to find the cause. Different browsers/computers have this issue.

I´m using XAMPP so i dont have a live version and the site is too big to post the functions.

How can i debug this? Does Firebug or any other browser tool can help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a form enclosing the button... add `type="button"` to the button and try

Comment: That was the problem! Added `type="button"` to all 3 buttons and resolved the issue. But it worked before with only two buttons, so i didint have a clue the problem was in the buttons inside a form. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because if you place a button inside a form, by default in will act like `type="submit"`.

So just add `type="button"` to those buttons.